# How to keep maps following my-location (moving the camera) and don't have OnCameraChange triggered

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

How can I keep the my-location blue icon centered without having to call moveCamera or without having it to trigger the onCameraChangeListener?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer is: you cannot.

You may want to post feature request like API to track user location: GoogleMap.setFollowingUserLocation or something like this on [gmaps-api-issues](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/list?can=2&q=apitype%3DAndroid2).